# Linux show different files on a directory when switching user

Tags: linux

First of all, sorry if this is an already answered question. I have this server with multiple users where i need to use the same ssh key in order to clone repositories. So i'm using the same key for each user. The way i did that was copying the ssh folder from my root user to each user dir. Changing the ownership to the respective user. When i access from root's account, the files are there. But when i switch to the user owner from the respective home folder, the ssh keys just dissapear.

[image]

Comment: You did notice that `pwd` gave two different answers, right?

Comment: You did access two different directories: /home/shopbusmultimarc (from root) and /dados/www/html/shopbusmultimarc (from user). Use "~shopbusmultimarc" path to get real home dir or the user (`cp -r path_to_ssh/.ssh ~shopbusmultimarc/`).

Comment: Thank you guys i didnt notice that when i switch user i also change the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/home/shopbusmultimarc`

and

`/dados/www/html/shopbusmultimarc`

Do not appear to be the same directories. So there is no reason to suspect they'd contain the same files.

as root, try `cd /dados/www/html/shopbusmultimarc` and then ls from there. You'll see the same files (or vice-versa).